# unable to click elements after animation gif using appium

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I want to perform search option after login and we have animation and GIF image in the loading time of login. Till now my code works fine but after login I could not able to find any element on the screen in emulator but if I run the same code on mobile device I am able to identify element but could not able to click(Click action is not reflecting on the screen)

```
@Test
public static void testhjg() throws MalformedURLException {
File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "APP");
File app = new File(appDir, "app-release (3).apk");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities =new DesiredCapabilities();        
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");                
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "My device");              
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0.1");             
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");  
capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", APPDetails.appPackage);    
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", APPDetails.appActivity);
capabilities.setCapability("app-wait-activity", "com.parkquility.ui.authentication.AuthenticationActivity");    
capabilities.setCapability("app-wait-activity", "com.parkquility.ui.home.HomeActivity");
capabilities.setCapability("app-wait-activity", "com.parkquility.ui.Profile.ProfileActivity");

capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout","240");

driver= new io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.findElementById("googleButton").click();
driver.findElementById("com.google.android.gms:id/account_name").click();

MobileElement ProfileTab = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.id("findParkingView"));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(ProfileTab));
ProfileTab.click();
```

Here I have provided my code

```
NoElementError - reflecting
```

Could you please any one help in this issue

Comment: How can you set the app-wait-activity three times consecutively to three different activities?  Wouldn't only the last one stick, or do you just prefer that to not commenting-out the two you don't want to use?  Also, your webdriver should probably be defined as AndroidDriver<MobileElement> (or AndroidElement) so it knows to search for resource-id and not id.

Comment: @BillHileman since my app contains multiple app activities ,I have just added to verify

Comment: @BillHileman i Have tried with AndroidDriver<MobileElement> as a driver,now able to locate element but click() action is not reflecting on app

Comment: Below is the console report-Responding to client with driver.click() result: true